# I'm trying to make an image uploading website using php, mysql and ajax..but I keep getting no output at all

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make an image uploading website where users can post their images and other logged-in users can reply to them. I'm trying to make this using php, mysql and ajax. I'm actually following a tutorial and I have modified their code to suit my website. But everytime I click submit, the page seems to refresh because I'm redirected to the top of my website and the new comment is not posted on top of the old comments as I want it to and also there is no inserting of the information of the new comment in the commentstable in my database.

Here is the code:

This is the php file in which I display the image and print out the comments and set a textarea to input new comments by the user. In this file, I import a javascript file which contains a function called postcomment() that performs the ajax part. The comments table has a column called commentForImageId which stores the id of the image for which a particular comment is posted.

```
<?php 
//image is displayed above this set of code with all the required data

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');//to set my country's timezone
?>

<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return postcomment();">
    <input type="hidden" id="imageId" value="<?php echo $imageId; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="datetime" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Write comment"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit">post comment</button>
</form>

<div id="allcomments">
    <?php

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM commentstable ORDER BY datetime DESC";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        $commentForImageId=$row['commentForImageId'];

        if($commentForImageId==$imageId){
            $username=$row['commentByUserName'];
            $comment=$row['comment'];
            $datetime=$row['datetime'];
    ?>
    <hr>
    <div class="comment_div"> 
    <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
    <p class="username">Posted By:<?php echo $username; ?></p>  
    <p class="datetime"><?php echo $datetime; ?></p>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <?php
}}?>
</div>
```

Here is the function that performs the ajax part. "commentsystem.php" performs the part of storing the data in the databse:

```
function postcomment(){
var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
var datetime = document.getElementById("datetime").value;
if(comment && datetime)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'commentsystem.php',
        data: 
        {
            comment:comment,
            datetime:datetime
        },
        success: function (response) 
        {
            document.getElementById("allcomments").innerHTML=response+document.getElementById("allcomments").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("comment").value="";
        }
    });
}

return false;
}
```

Here is commentsystem.php. Here, "dbh.php" is the database handling file where the connection to the database is established:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'dbh.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){//if user has logged in
    if(isset($_POST['comment']) && isset($_POST['datetime']) && isset($_POST['imageId']))
    {
    //if user has submitted the comment
    $comment=$_POST['comment'];
    $datetime=$_POST['datetime'];
    $imageId=$_POST['imageId'];
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
    $userId=$_SESSION['id'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO commentstable (commentForImageId, commentByUserId, commentByUserName, likes, numberOfReplies, comment, datetime) VALUES ('$imageId', '$userId', '$username', 0, 0, '$comment', '$datetime')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    ?>

    <div class="comment_div"> 
        <p class="comment"><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
        <p class="username">Posted By:<?php echo $username; ?></p>  
        <p class="datetime"><?php echo $datetime; ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    exit;
}   
}
else{   
    header("LOCATION: signup.php");
}
?>
```

Thank you very much for your help! I'm very new to this and am completely confused about what is going wrong!

Thanks in advance once again!

Comment: look at your console, check for errors using php's error reporting and on the query/queries also.

Comment: on an unrelated note, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks and javascript injection attacks from hackers. you should fix those before you get hacked

Comment: I don't get any errors..just that nothing happens so I am not able to understand what is going wrong

Comment: and about the sql injection thanks, hanshenrik, for pointing it out and I am indeed going to take care of it once the code starts working..thanks again though :)

Comment: you also say you're wanting to upload images; I don't see any code related to that, not to handle/upload anyway. You say you're not getting errors; I don't see any error checking at all.  again, look at your console for JS and php http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I also don't see where `$_SESSION['id']` gets assigned nor do we know if it is assigned elsewhere on a page you didn't include. and if you're using `http://localhost` on your own machine (or hosted) or as `file:///`. Many unknowns.

Comment: I have already written code for uploading images.. I have also written code for assigning the session variables...just that I have not included it here because I thought that would be out of the scope of the question..and I'm using localhost to run the code

Comment: So i checked the console for errors, it says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"..what does that signify?

Comment: @eagleAtlantis That usually means your you have no Jquery loaded

Comment: ohkay so I have loaded JQuery now and that error is not appearing anymore but the code still doesn't perform its function

Comment: @eagleAtlantis Where do you call the postcomment() function?

Comment: <form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return postcomment();"> here @Moishey Schwartz

Comment: @eagleAtlantis I would give the button a class for example `postcomment` and the call this `$('.postcomment').click( function(){ $.ajax....  return false;})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131287/discussion-between-eagleatlantis-and-moishey-schwartz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the button a class for example postcomment and the call this `$('.postcomment').click( function(){ $.ajax.... return false;})`

Also make sure you set the $imageId as in commentsystem.php you require it to be set

Comment: Can you explain why it wasn't working in the way that I was using before?

Comment: yes yes it is working perfectly now but I was curious to know why it doesnt work without using JQuery

Comment: $.ajax is a Jquery method